# different values between print and pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

So I try scraping multiple news by providing it into a dataframe that will converted into list.But when I insert into dataframe it only give last value of scraping but print have show different result.My example df is like this

```
df = {data:['https://www.liputan6.com/bisnis/read/4661489/erick-thohir-apresiasi-transformasi-digital-pos-indonesia],
            [https://ekonomi.bisnis.com/read/20211010/98/1452514/hari-pos-sedunia-pos-indonesia-kasih-diskon-70-persen-paket-kilat]}
```

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
df = pd.read_excel(' 1.xlsx')
urls = df['data'].to_list()


for url in urls:
    try:
        a = Article(url, language='id')
        a.download()
        a.parse()

        author = a.authors
        dates = a.publish_date
        add_data = a.additional_data
        text = a.text
        tag = a.tags
        title = a.title
        keywords = a.keywords

        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'author':[author]}) #it need in [] because it can be multiple  
        print(author,dates,add_data,text,tag,title,keywords)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

when I run the `print(author)` it show a result

```
['S. Dian Andryanto', 'Reporter', 'Editor']
['Ali Akhmad Noor Hidayat', 'Reporter', 'Editor']
```

But when I inserted to dataframe they only return the last value

```
new_data = {"author":['Ali Akhmad Noor Hidayat', 'Reporter', 'Editor']}
```

Anyone can explain how to get all my author inserted to dataframe?

Comment: Probably, this is because you are creating the dataframe `new_df` for each loop with the list of `Authors`, hence the last entry is overwritten on previous entries. You have to `extend` the list into one list and then out of the `for` loop, create the dataframe with the extended list of all authors.

Comment: When you run `new_df = pd.DataFrame({'author':[author]})` you create a dataframe with one column named 'author' and one row which is what is contained in the variable `author`, because the list `[author]` has only one element. In order to have multiple rows you should run something like `new_df = pd.DataFrame({'author': list_of_authors})`, where `list_of_authors` is a list containing all the rows you want in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the `urls` list and inside the loop you re-create each time the entire DataFrame stored in `new_df`. To avoid this, you can
create an external dictionary and at the end of the loop create the entire DataFrame, like in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
df = pd.read_excel(' 1.xlsx')
urls = df['data'].to_list()

all_authors = {"author": []}
for url in urls:
   try:
     a = Article(url, language='id')
     a.download()
     a.parse()

     author = a.authors
     dates = a.publish_date
     add_data = a.additional_data
     text = a.text
     tag = a.tags
     title = a.title
     keywords = a.keywords

     all_authors['author'].append(author) #it need in [] because it can be multiple  
    

   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_authors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect `new_df` in a list and concat them at the end.

*I slightly modified your code because catch all exception is a bad idea, use `newspaper.ArticleException` instead.*

```
urls = ['https://www.liputan6.com/bisnis/read/4661489/erick-thohir-apresiasi-transformasi-digital-pos-indonesia',
        'https://ekonomi.bisnis.com/read/20211010/98/1452514/hari-pos-sedunia-pos-indonesia-kasih-diskon-70-persen-paket-kilat']

data = []
for url in urls:
    try:
        a = Article(url, language='id')
        a.download()
        a.parse()

    except newspaper.ArticleException as e:
        print(e)

    else:    
        author = a.authors
        dates = a.publish_date
        add_data = a.additional_data
        text = a.text
        tag = a.tags
        title = a.title
        keywords = a.keywords

        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'author':[author]})
        data.append(new_df)        

df = pd.concat(data)
```